pyTelegramBotAPI: set_message_reaction() - How do I make my Telegram bot react with a specific emoji to any message it recieves?
This is my code:
import telebot

BOT_TOKEN = '-'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message:True)
def thumbs_up(message):
    bot.set_message_reaction(message.chat.id, message.id, '')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling()

And this is the error I get:
    payload['reaction'] = json.dumps([r.to_dict() for r in reaction])
                                      ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

I don't understand how I can use a JSON list like the docs say:
https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.set_message_reaction
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmessagereaction
It also says in the docs that the reaction parameter is optional but I get an error if I don't include it.

The reaction should be a list, not a single emoji.
Use it like so:
from telebot.types import ReactionTypeEmoji

bot.set_message_reaction(message.chat.id, message.id, [ReactionTypeEmoji('')], is_big=False)

